# Elastic Search (COUNT*) with group by and where condition

Tags: elasticsearch

Dear ElasticSearch users,

I am newbie in ElasticSearch.

I am confused for how to convert the following sql command into ElasticSearch DSL query ? Can anyone help to assist me.

```
  SELECT ip,
         count(*) AS c
    FROM elastic 
   WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-08-20  00:00:00' AND '2016-08-22 13:41:09' 
         AND service='http' 
         AND destination='10.17.102.1'
GROUP BY ip 
ORDER BY c DESC;
```

Thank You

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The following query will achieve exactly what you want, i.e. it will select the documents within the desired `date` range and with the required `service` and `destination` and then run a `terms` aggregation (=group by) on their `ip` field and order the latter in decreasing count order.

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gt": "2016-08-22T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lt": "2016-08-22T13:41:09.000Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "service": "http"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "destination": "10.17.102.1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_ip": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir @Val, thank you for the assits. Can I ask another combination that i keep looking at. How to do SUM_ALL(volume that used) on each ip , and finally shown for example(ip:xxxx, volume:20mb) under aggregation.

Thank You

Comment: Simpe, thanks for giving a way to list count/length of aggregated results in elastic search