# How to make aggregations on field basis in NEST and Elastic Search?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, dsl

I would like to perform aggregation in Elastic Search using NEST which would mimic the below SQL query:

```
select region, bucket, count(dispositioncode)
from tbl
group by region, bucket
```

My attempt so far

```
var dispositionCodes = new TermsQuery
            {
                IsVerbatim = true,
                Field = "trailstatus",
                Terms = new string[] { "TR" }
            };

ISearchResponse<TrailReportModel> searchResponse =
               ConnectionToES.EsClient()
               .Search<TrailReportModel>
               (s => s
                   .Index(feedbackIndex)
                   .From(0)
                   .Size(RecordSize)
                     .Query(q => q.MatchAll()
                             
                                .Aggregations(fa => fa

                              .Filter("disp_aggs", f => f.Filter(fd => dispositionCodes))                              
                      )
                      
var result = ((Nest.SingleBucketAggregate)searchResponse.Aggregations["disp_aggs"]).DocCount;
```

This gives me the count for the entire records irrespective of Region and Bucket. But I am looking for the Count per Region and Bucket basis.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why I have been downvoted? I have asked because I failed to solve the problem (:

Comment: I have restored the original post, as posts are much more likely to be answered if they show some prior effort. It is not clear why that part of your question was deleted.

Comment: Readers cannot tell you why you have received a downvote, since the voter did not comment to say why they voted. My guess is that the "please help me" begging was a bit needy, and that doesn't tend to go down well here.  A quick count of the edits made to your posts shows that pleading or chatty material has been removed at least 70 times from your earlier questions. Technical writing is preferred here.

Comment: The SQL Translate API would probably get you a good way in how to express this in the query DSL: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit difficult without a case to test, but you may want to use the [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) (in [NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-aggregation-usage.html)).

With this, you could specify something like:

```
.Aggregations(a => a
     .Terms("group_by_region", t => t.Field("region"))
     .Terms("group_by_bucket", t => t.Field("bucket")))
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113842/elastic-search-count-with-group-by-and-where-condition) may also help, it is a similar problem :)

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar did this help?